# How to get accumulated price in a nested array using reduce in React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I have an array of objects (cart products). In each object, there is an array of "ShopCartList", and productCartList another array of objects. How can I accumulate the price of all "Price" for each product? The cart API [image]

The goal is to get the total price and also total price when adding products from a different shop.

```json
{
  "CartID": "610a20c7d51ba524b7f949cd",
  "ShopCartList": [
    {
      "ShopID": "610a29e1d51ba524b7f949d0",
      "productCartList": [
        {
          "ProductID": "610a33f7d51ba524b7f949df",
          "VariationSKU": "062101403N",
          "Price": 2385.96,
          "Count": 1,
          "Attribute": {
            "Weight": "8.29",
            "Diameter": "5.40"
          },
          "CreatedDate": "2021-11-15T06:43:36.482Z",
          "CreatedBy": "610a20c7d51ba524b7f949cd",
          "LastUpdatedDate": "2021-11-15T06:43:36.482Z",
          "LastUpdatedBy": "610a20c7d51ba524b7f949cd"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

it shows an error of undefined.

[image]

Comment: if you can send text in JSON, so people can use the code, this reduce you want to do it in javascript? or inside MongoDB?

Comment: wanted to do this code in javascript.

Comment: [this might help you](https://dev.to/yogesnsamy/how-to-use-the-reduce-method-in-javascript-and-react-5dhl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can reduce to get the sum of a certain key from an array of objects.

```js
ProductCartList.reduce((a,b) => {
  return a + b["Price"]
},0);
```

The above code returns the total sum of prices of products from a single `productCartList` array. If you have multiple items inside your `ShopCartList` array and want to get the sum of all the prices from all the `ProductCartList`s, you can use reduce on the `ShopCartList` array like so

```js
ShopCartList.reduce((a,b) => {
  return a + b["ProductCartList"].reduce((a,b) => return a + b["Price"]);
},0);
```

The above code get adds the sum of all the prices from all the different product carts.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I'm getting error od undefined "reduce" .

Comment: The undefined error occurs because the `data.ShopCartList` object is undefined. Can you share the output of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: thank you for helping, I have solved the error. the solution for it was I added as  total = data.data.ShopCartList.reduce(
      (a, b) =>
        a + b.productCartList.reduce((c, d) => c + d.Price * d.Count, 0),
      0
    );